# Телеграм бот на python. дублирование сообщений

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Проблема заключается в том, что если выключен интернет у пользователя и он нажал команду старт несколько раз, то запускается сразу несколько одинаковых процессов в боте.

[image: программа]

код:

```
import telebot

bot_token = 'токен'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token, parse_mode=None)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Фамилия:")
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_name)

def get_name(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Имя:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, get_patronymic)

def get_patronymic(message):
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Отчество:')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Думаю вам стоит посмотреть на aiogram ибо там есть свой throttling который, думаю решит вашу проблему

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте заменить Вашу строчку `@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])` на `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "/start")`.

Comment: Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, то, пожалуйста, отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: не помогло. то что вы написали - по сути то же самое. можно решить проблему если избавиться от  register_next_step_handler и сделать каждую функцию независимой, но пока не знаю - как.

Answer (score 0):

Оберните bot.send_message в функцию. В ней должен быть словарь где ключ userid а значение текст сообщения. Вызываете функцию, передаете ей userid и текст. Функция проверяет есть ли в словаре по ключу userid значение, и если нет выполняет send_message и вносит в словарь отправленный текст по ключу userid. Если есть, сравнивает текст подлежащий отправке с текстом из словаря. Если они совпадают, то ничего не делает. Но я когда такое делал, в этом месте удалял сообщение пользователя, и таким образом у него перед глазами всегда последнее сообщение от бота.
Если не совпадают, то выполняет send_message, и вносит в словарь отправленный текст по ключу userid.
Если дальше нужно использовать next_step_handler, то соответственно делаете return.
И это будет работать с любыми текстовыми сообщениями.
А если нужно из другого места программы всё таки отправить текст аналогичный предыдущему, то перед send_message просто делаете lastmsgtext[userid]=‘’

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю как быть с сообщениями, но у меня была подобная проблема при обработке колбэков: при нажатии инлайн кнопки на айфонах - сообщение приходило 3 раза в ответ, всё облазил и каким то чудом узнал об этом:

```
telegram_bot.answer_callback_query(call.id)
```

Просто сообщить телеге что мы обработали колбэк и всё, он перестаёт дублировать запросы. Возможно вам стоит поискать подобный подход.